# Communicating Azure Web app with WCF Web App

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, azure-web-app-service

I need to host ASP.NET based app as Azure Web App which should communicate with WCF based Azure Web App.  ( WCF app is also an azure Web App not an on-premise app at all).

What are possible ways to achieve easy and flexible communication between both app services?

Do we need to establish a communication channel specifically?

Both Apps under IIS On-Premises are used to communicate without any problem over NET TCP protocol. But I think now we need both services to communicate over HTTP instead of Net TCP?

What problems we may have?
What things do we need to bear in mind?

Comment: What do you mean by `communicate` between two webapps?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, we need to be clear that azure webapp only supports ports 80 and 443.**

Secondly, in your project, you said that it runs normally in local, because I don't know what you mean by `communicate`, and I don't know how to achieve it. Normal communication may be socket or websocket, etc. It is not clear what communication you are talking about. If it is socket and you need to use a port other than 443/80, then it is not supported.

But I know clearly that azure web app supports wcf, which means that both of your webapps can be deployed successfully and run normally. If there is a problem, you can update the error details in the post, and we can provide you with further assistance.

Comment: I have posted a question here. The same behavior what I was expecting, I got 
so, I posted seperately.
Could you help me in this context? @Jason Pan
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69150039/hosted-wcf-on-azure-app-service-not-responding-to-client-app-service